# Include graphics in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I am newbie to LaTeX and I have a simple problem including graphics to the text. When I run

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.25cm,height=0.25cm]{Figure1}
\caption[Sèries temporals de vent i direccions]{Sèries temporals velocitat de vent       direccions. filtratge de pics i glaçades de velocitat.}
\label{Serie}
\end{center}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I create a `pdf` file but there is no figure inserted. The picture is called `Figure1.png` but it seems that the program do not recognizes it and doesn't inserts it. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: which engine are you using? latex? pdflatex? or? And can you show the log file generated? And try add the extension `.png` to the filename in your source.

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting? Note that for PNGs you need to use the modern `pdflatex`, not the classic `latex`. If you tell us which editor etc. you are using and state the error message (from e.g. the `.log` file) we may help you better. As a general node: Please use `\centering` instead of `center` in `figure`s, see [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651).

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I use Text Maker and PDFLatex. I get no errors at all.

Comment: @jonel-r: Could you please register you account here, then it will be synced with the one on stackoverflow.com and you will get ownership of this post here again. Otherwise you won't be able to post comments and accept answers for it.

Answer (score 8):

You are not getting any error at all!. Interesting. This naswer is based on a **pure guess**. Basically your problem is perhaps the dimensions of the figure you are using in `\includegraphics[width=0.25cm,height=0.25cm]{Figure1}`. The length `0.25cm` itself is a small dimension and depending on your figure (like the white space it may have around etc.), your figure may not be visible at all. If you magnify say, 400 times you may be able to see something.

As such your figure dimensions are looking like this:

[image]

The black box is your figure.

Now try with these dimesions:

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{Figure1}
```

This is the dimension you should see:

[image]

The above assumes that your figure file is in the same folder as your tex file. Also, as mentioned in comments, put `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...` to avoid extra (unnecessary) vertical space.

If your problem is still not solved, additional details may be necessary for diagnosis. (If you provide your figure file `Figure1.png`, it might have been better.)